# Doctrine The target-entity cannot be found in

Tags: php, entity-framework, symfony, doctrine-orm, orm

I receive this error on my server when trying to load my webpage:
The target-entity ArcaSolutions\ListingBundle\Entity\Classified cannot be found in 'ArcaSolutions\ListingBundle\Entity\Listing#classified'.
I've no doubt that the issue is that the target-entity is referencing ListingBundle instead of ClassifiedBundle, but I don't see anywhere in my code where I could have made this mistake.

So far I've tried restarting Apache, and clearing doctrine cache.

Here is the code for the Classified.php (MyProject\src\ArcaSolutions\ClassifiedBundle\Entity\Classified.php)

```
namespace ArcaSolutions\ClassifiedBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\JoinColumn;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation as Serializer;

/**
* Classified
*
* @ORM\Table(name="Classified", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="country_id", columns={"location_1"}), @ORM\Index(name="state_id", columns={"location_2"}), @ORM\Index(name="region_id", columns={"location_3"}), @ORM\Index(name="latitude", columns={"latitude"}), @ORM\Index(name="longitude", columns={"longitude"}), @ORM\Index(name="level", columns={"level"}), @ORM\Index(name="status", columns={"status"}), @ORM\Index(name="account_id", columns={"account_id"}), @ORM\Index(name="city_id", columns={"location_4"}), @ORM\Index(name="area_id", columns={"location_5"}), @ORM\Index(name="title", columns={"title"}), @ORM\Index(name="friendly_url", columns={"friendly_url"}), @ORM\Index(name="cat_1_id", columns={"cat_1_id"}), @ORM\Index(name="parcat_1_level1_id", columns={"parcat_1_level1_id"}), @ORM\Index(name="fulltextsearch_keyword", columns={"fulltextsearch_keyword"}), @ORM\Index(name="fulltextsearch_where", columns={"fulltextsearch_where"})})
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="ArcaSolutions\ClassifiedBundle\Repository\ClassifiedRepository")
*/
class Classified
{
    /**
    * @var integer
    *
    * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
    * @Serializer\Groups({"classifiedDetail", "Result", "listingDetail"})
    */
    private $id;

    /**
    * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ArcaSolutions\ListingBundle\Entity\Listing", mappedBy="classified")
    * @ORM\OrderBy({"status" = "ASC"})
    * @Serializer\Groups({"classifiedDetail", "Result"})
    * @Serializer\Type("array")
    */
    private $listingArray;

    /**
    * Constructor
    */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->listingArray = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
    * Add listingArray
    *
    * @param \ArcaSolutions\ListingBundle\Entity\Listing $listingArray
    * @return Classified
    */
    public function addListingArray(\ArcaSolutions\ListingBundle\Entity\Listing $listingArray)
    {
        $this->listingArray[] = $listingArray;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
    * Remove listingArray
    *
    * @param \ArcaSolutions\ListingBundle\Entity\Listing $listingArray
    */
    public function removeListingArray(\ArcaSolutions\ListingBundle\Entity\Listing $listingArray)
    {
        $this->listingArray->removeElement($listingArray);
    }

    /**
    * Get listingArray
    *
    * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
    */
    public function getListingArray()
    {
        return $this->listingArray;
    }
}
```

Here is the code for the Listing.php (MyProject\src\ArcaSolutions\ListingBundle\Entity\Listing.php)

```
namespace ArcaSolutions\ListingBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\JoinColumn;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation as Serializer;


/**
* Listing
*
* @ORM\Table(name="Listing", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="title", columns={"title"}), @ORM\Index(name="country_id", columns={"location_1"}), @ORM\Index(name="state_id", columns={"location_2"}), @ORM\Index(name="region_id", columns={"location_3"}), @ORM\Index(name="account_id", columns={"account_id"}), @ORM\Index(name="renewal_date", columns={"renewal_date"}), @ORM\Index(name="status", columns={"status"}), @ORM\Index(name="latitude", columns={"latitude"}), @ORM\Index(name="longitude", columns={"longitude"}), @ORM\Index(name="level", columns={"level"}), @ORM\Index(name="city_id", columns={"location_4"}), @ORM\Index(name="area_id", columns={"location_5"}), @ORM\Index(name="zip_code", columns={"zip_code"}), @ORM\Index(name="friendly_url", columns={"friendly_url"}), @ORM\Index(name="listingtemplate_id", columns={"listingtemplate_id"}), @ORM\Index(name="image_id", columns={"image_id"}), @ORM\Index(name="thumb_id", columns={"thumb_id"}), @ORM\Index(name="idx_fulltextsearch_keyword", columns={"fulltextsearch_keyword"}), @ORM\Index(name="idx_fulltextsearch_where", columns={"fulltextsearch_where"}), @ORM\Index(name="updated_date", columns={"updated"}), @ORM\Index(name="clicktocall_number", columns={"clicktocall_number"}), @ORM\Index(name="Listing_Promotion", columns={"level", "account_id", "title", "id"})})
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="ArcaSolutions\ListingBundle\Repository\ListingRepository")
*/
class Listing
{
    /**
    * @var integer
    *
    * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
    * @Serializer\Groups({"listingDetail", "Result", "classifiedDetail", "dealDetail", "reviewItem"})
    */
    private $id;

    /**
    * @var integer
    *
    * @ORM\Column(name="classified_id", type="integer", nullable=true)
    */
    private $classifiedId;

    /**
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="ArcaSolutions\ClassifiedBundle\Entity\Classified", inversedBy="listingArray")
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="classified_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    * @Serializer\Groups({"listingDetail"})
    */
    private $classified;

    /**
    * Set classifiedId
    *
    * @param integer $classifiedId
    * @return Listing
    */
    public function setClassifiedId($classifiedId)
    {
        $this->classifiedId = $classifiedId;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
    * Get classifiedId
    *
    * @return integer 
    */
    public function getClassifiedId()
    {
        return $this->classifiedId;
    }

    /**
    * Set classified
    *
    * @param \ArcaSolutions\ClassifiedBundle\Entity\Classified $classified
    * @return Listing
    */
    public function setClassified(\ArcaSolutions\ClassifiedBundle\Entity\Classified $classified = null)
    {
        $this->classified = $classified;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
    * Get classified
    *
    * @return \ArcaSolutions\ClassifiedBundle\Entity\Classified 
    */
    public function getClassified()
    {
        return $this->classified;
    }

    /**
    * Add classifieds
    *
    * @param \ArcaSolutions\ClassifiedBundle\Entity\Classified $classifieds
    * @return Listing
    */
    public function addClassified(\ArcaSolutions\ClassifiedBundle\Entity\Classified $classifieds)
    {
        $this->classifieds[] = $classifieds;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
    * Remove classifieds
    *
    * @param \ArcaSolutions\ClassifiedBundle\Entity\Classified $classifieds
    */
    public function removeClassified(\ArcaSolutions\ClassifiedBundle\Entity\Classified $classifieds)
    {
        $this->classifieds->removeElement($classifieds);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try deleting `classifiedId` in your listing as you do not need it and it is maybe making a problem

Comment: Have you tried restarting Apache / php-fpm ? If you have apc cache enabled just clearing cache folder is not enough.
Also could you show full file names for both files?

Comment: @kunicmarko20 Deleting classifiedId did not make a difference, still received the same error after removing it.

Comment: @MaksymMoskvychev I've restarted Apache to ensure the cache cleared, still received the same error. Also I included the full path names from the root folder of MyProject.

Comment: It is looking for your entity in wrong place `ArcaSolutions\ListingBundle\Entity\Classified` this entity is in `ClassifiedBundle` and not `Listing` did you clear your doctrine cache maybe?

Comment: @kunicmarko20 I tried clearing the cache using these 3 commands, however I'm still receiving the same error: php app/console doctrine:cache:clear-metadata
php app/console doctrine:cache:clear-query
php app/console doctrine:cache:clear-result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get the error to go away by renaming $classified to $theclassified, changing mappedBy="classified" to mappedBy="theclassified", regenerating the two bundles and updating the db schema. I'm not sure how this fixed the error because I'm not referencing $classified anywhere else so that's strange. Also I'm getting a separate error now which I will post a separate question for.

Answer (score 0):

**Your problem is not related to these 2 entities**.
Look, maybe you have another entities with the same namespace in project? (copy-paste issues?) Maybe something left after refactoring.

I've created 2 bundles with your names, 2 entities with your content and it works just fine (except for indexes, which are defined for not-existing fields). I was able to generate valid migration, also Doctrine says "0 invalid entities":

```
CREATE TABLE Classified (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, PRIMARY 
KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ENGINE = 
InnoDB;
CREATE TABLE Listing (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, classified_id 
INT DEFAULT NULL, INDEX IDX_4BD7148A0B0417E (classified_id), PRIMARY 
KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ENGINE = 
InnoDB;
ALTER TABLE Listing ADD CONSTRAINT FK_4BD7148A0B0417E FOREIGN KEY 
(classified_id) REFERENCES Classified (id);
```

Comment: Moskvychev it has to be these 2 entities, I can comment out the private declarations for $classified and $listingArray and the webpage loads fine. (i.e. //private $classified;)